# Nativescript: Zeroconf/Bonjour discovery on iOS callbacks not working

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am trying to perform a Zeroconf/Bonjour discovery on iOS in my Nativescript application. I am using the code below, but the problem is that `WillSearch` or `DidStopSearch` or other callbacks never fire:

```
this.netServiceBrowser = NSNetServiceBrowser.new();

this.netServiceBrowser.delegate = <NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate> {
  netServiceBrowserDidFindDomainMoreComing: (browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, domainString: string, moreComing: boolean) => {
    console.log(`netServiceBrowserDidFindDomainMoreComing: ${domainString}`);
  },
  netServiceBrowserWillSearch: (browser:NSNetServiceBrowser) => {
    console.log(`netServiceBrowserWillSearch`);
  },
  netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch: (browser:NSNetServiceBrowser) => {
    console.log(`netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch`);
  },
  netServiceBrowserDidFindServiceMoreComing: (browser:NSNetServiceBrowser, service:NSNetService, moreComing:boolean) => {
    console.log(`netServiceBrowserDidFindServiceMoreComing, found service ${service.name}`);
    console.log(`moreComing: ${moreComing}`);
  }
}

this.netServiceBrowser.searchForRegistrationDomains(); // start searching for domains
this.netServiceBrowser.searchForServicesOfTypeInDomain(this.config.bonjour.serviceType, this.config.bonjour.serviceDomain);
setTimeout(() => { this.netServiceBrowser.stop(); },30000); // stop discovery after 30 secs
```

My guess is that I am doing something wrong with the definition of the ‘callbacks’ in the delegate, but I have no clue as to what.

This is the relevant section of the typings:

```
declare class NSNetServiceBrowser extends NSObject {
  static alloc(): NSNetServiceBrowser; // inherited from NSObject
  static new(): NSNetServiceBrowser; // inherited from NSObject
  delegate: NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate;
  includesPeerToPeer: boolean;
  removeFromRunLoopForMode(aRunLoop: NSRunLoop, mode: string): void;
  scheduleInRunLoopForMode(aRunLoop: NSRunLoop, mode: string): void;
  searchForBrowsableDomains(): void;
  searchForRegistrationDomains(): void;
  searchForServicesOfTypeInDomain(type: string, domainString: string): void;
  stop(): void;
}

interface NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate extends NSObjectProtocol {
  netServiceBrowserDidFindDomainMoreComing?(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, domainString: string, moreComing: boolean): void;
  netServiceBrowserDidFindServiceMoreComing?(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, service: NSNetService, moreComing: boolean): void;
  netServiceBrowserDidNotSearch?(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, errorDict: NSDictionary<string, number>): void;
  netServiceBrowserDidRemoveDomainMoreComing?(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, domainString: string, moreComing: boolean): void;
  netServiceBrowserDidRemoveServiceMoreComing?(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, service: NSNetService, moreComing: boolean): void;
  netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch?(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser): void;
  netServiceBrowserWillSearch?(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser): void;
}
declare var NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate: {
  prototype: NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate;
};
```

Thanks for any pointers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested in this, I was able to solve it with the help of someone nice from the NativeScript community (thanks!):

```
/* Define NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate implementation class */

class MyNSNetServiceBrowserDelegate extends NSObject implements NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate {
  public static ObjCProtocols = [NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate];

  static new(): MyNSNetServiceBrowserDelegate {
    return <MyNSNetServiceBrowserDelegate>super.new();
  }

  private _callback: (result: string) => void;

  public initWithCallback(callback: (result: string) => void): MyNSNetServiceBrowserDelegate {
    this._callback = callback;
    return this;
  }

  public netServiceBrowserDidFindDomainMoreComing(browser: NSNetServiceBrowser, domainString: string, moreComing: boolean) {
    console.log(`netServiceBrowserDidFindDomainMoreComing: ${domainString}`);
    this._callback(domainString);
  }

  public netServiceBrowserWillSearch(browser:NSNetServiceBrowser) {
    console.log(`netServiceBrowserWillSearch`);
  }

  public netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch(browser:NSNetServiceBrowser) {
    console.log(`netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch`);
  }

  public netServiceBrowserDidFindServiceMoreComing(browser:NSNetServiceBrowser, service:NSNetService, moreComing:boolean) {
    console.log(`netServiceBrowserDidFindServiceMoreComing, found service ${service.name}`);
    console.log(`moreComing: ${moreComing}`);
    this._callback(service.name);
  }
}
```

Then something like this in the provider:

```
@Injectable()
export class BonjourProvider {
  private netServiceBrowser:NSNetServiceBrowser;

  constructor(private config:ConfigProvider) {
    this.netServiceBrowser = NSNetServiceBrowser.new();
  }

  public startDeviceDiscovery() {
    this.netServiceBrowser.delegate = MyNSNetServiceBrowserDelegate.new().initWithCallback(result => console.log(`MyNSNetServiceBrowserDelegate callback: ${result}`));

    // this.netServiceBrowser.searchForRegistrationDomains();
    this.netServiceBrowser.searchForServicesOfTypeInDomain('_http._tcp', 'local');
  }
}
```